# Is anyone aware of Mathematica implementation of OpenAI's GPT-3 API?

Tags: neural-networks, implementation-details, api, chatai

Is anyone aware of Mathematica's implementation of OpenAI's GPT-3 API?

Comment: No. I don't believe they have yet trained a GPT-3 or created the underlying network for one. However, a trained GPT-2 is available: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/GPT2-Transformer-Trained-on-WebText-Data/

Comment: Please see this post [access GPT3 api with MMA](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279716/access-openai-with-httprequest-but-body-parameters-seems-not-function)

Comment: There's also a GPT-2 implementation demo on the Wolfram Community site:  https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1728566

Answer (score 7):

There is a paclet
[OpenAILink](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/ChristopherWolfram/OpenAILink/) (by Christopher Wolfram):

[image]

---

Also, check-out the paclet
['OpenAIMode'](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/AntonAntonov/OpenAIMode/):

[image]