# Access openai with HTTPRequest but body parameters seems not function

Tags: web-access, apifunction, http-functions

Using Mathematica 13.0 on Windows 10

codes are below

```
req=HTTPRequest["https://api.openai.com/v1/completions",
<|Method->"POST",
"Body"->{"model"->"text-davinci-003","prompt"->"Say this is a test"},
"Headers"->{"Authorization"->"Bearer sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"}|>]
URLExecute[req]
```

and here is the output

```
{error->{message->you must provide a model parameter,type->invalid_request_error,param->Null,code->Null}}
```

It seems I set the wrong body parameters especially in `"model"` part.

First I checked the [openai Ducuments](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/making-requests) to set proper body parameters.Then I used postman to verify my body parameters and it works. However, when I try to reproduce POST request in Mathematica, the output returned by the site shows that I did not set body parameters correctly.

I also checked my request body by using

```
req["Body"]
```

and it returns normally

```
{"model": "text-davinci-003","prompt": "Say this is a test"}
```

I think the possible error is in setting the wrong format or position of the parameter.
Could anyone give me some suggestions or hints on setting body parameter?

Comment: Most likely that body need to be converted to JSON. Try using `"Body"->ExportString[{"model"->"text-davinci-003","prompt"->"Say this is a test"},"JSON"]`

Comment: @GustavoDelfino I tried and it returns the same error. You can directly evaluate your code to test because I provided the api key.

Comment: `<| Method -> "POST", "Body" ->   ExportString[{"model" -> "text-davinci-003", 
    "prompt" -> "Say this is a test"}, "JSON"], "ContentType" -> "application/json",`

Comment: @Kuba Thanks a lot!!! I didn't use the ```ContentType``` parameter to post request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Kuba's and GustavoDelfino's comments, the solution is to make sure to send a JSON body with a proper `content-type` header:

```
req = HTTPRequest[
  "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions",
  <| 
    Method -> "POST", 
    "Body" ->   ExportString[{"model" -> "text-davinci-003",      "prompt" -> "Say this is a test"}, "JSON"], 
    "ContentType" -> "application/json",
    "Headers" -> { "Authorization"-> ...} 
  |>
]

URLExecute[req]
```